# Create iptable rule to match UDP traffic with multiple source ports and a single destination port

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am trying to create an iptable rule that will match multiple source ports and a single destination port. I have tried the following rule but am met with this error:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --sports 30000:65535 --dport 3074 -j ACCEPT
iptables v1.4.21: multiport: option "--source-ports" cannot be used together with "--destination-ports".
```

I saw a post similar to this one where someone asked about routing traffic from certain ports and/or IP's to a single port/IP however that is not what I am trying to do. I want only traffic coming from those source ports going to that single destination port to be accepted.

I am using a default drop all policy, if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Dport is matching as a multiport option here, you should put it before:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 3074 -m multiport --sports 30000:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly!

Comment: Indeed. Then `--dport` becomes a parameter to the implicit `-m udp` match (which appears back when using `iptables -S INPUT` or `iptables-save`). This would also have worked: `iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --sports 30000:65535 -m udp --dport 3074 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Ah okay I understand now how the kernel would read the rule, thanks for clearing that up for me I really appreciate the help!